# Pourquoi dit-on « ça n'a ni queue ni tête » ?

Tags: expressions

D'où vient cette expression utilisée pour qualifier quelque chose d'incompréhensible ? Ça ne m'a jamais choqué jusqu'à récemment quand j'ai essayé d'expliquer cette expression dans une conversation...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Il me semble que la tête peut être comprise comme étant le début et la queue comme étant la fin. Sans ces deux éléments, on peut difficilement comprendre le sens de la chose. Ça n'a aucun fil conducteur qui tient le tout en place.

La définition de la locution dans le [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/queue) abonde en ce sens :

> *Sans queue ni tête.* (Qui semble être) sans début et sans fin, (qui est) en désordre.

Notons au passage que l'anglais possède une expression qui est sensiblement pareille : *not make head(s) or tail(s) of*.

Comment: +1 pour la simplicité, une autre façon d'expliquer http://www.actualitte.com/patrimoine/l-expressio-de-la-semaine-sans-queue-ni-tete-38224.htm avec des corrélations internationales intéressantes

Comment: J'ai toujours cru que *make head or tail* faisait référence à pile ou face?

Answer (score 0):

L'[article de wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histoire_sans_queue_ni_t%C3%AAte#:%7E:text=Une%20histoire%20sans%20queue%20ni,acm%C3%A9%20ou%20une%20chute%20inutile.) sur ce sujet est très pertinent. C'est donc à l'origine une histoire sans début ni fin, ce qui la rend très floue et difficile à comprendre.